# Adding Comments to a Model and Strong Parameters in Rails 4 Throwing an Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I started playing with Rails 4 last night. And I'm making a simple blog type app to become familiar with some of the changes. I have posts working with the default scaffolding.

I decided to work through adding comments without scaffolding and I'm getting this error when I try to save a comment on a post:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in CommentsController#create
```

Request Params ON Error Page:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"jkald9....",
 "comment"=>{"commenter"=>"Sam",
 "body"=>"I love this post!"},
 "commit"=>"Create Comment",
 "post_id"=>"1"}
```

Here is the comment controller's create action:

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
        def create
            @post = post.find(params[:post_id])
            @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
            redirect_to post_path(@post)
        end

        private

        def comment_params
          params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body, :post_id)
        end
    end
```

Here's the very basic migration for my comments.

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :post, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong with Strongly typed params? Or maybe there is something else that has changed in Rails 4 that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

Bit of an oversight,but I figured I would answer this question in case anyone else was working on porting similar Rails 3 code to Rails 4.

You need to pass comment_params into the mass assignment like this:

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by editing the comments_controller  create function to

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

note the

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
```

Best Regards